# Representing a 3D array as a block-diagonal matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Given a 3-dimensional array `A`: each slice is a matrix `An`. I would like to represent `A` as a block-diagonal matrix as follows:

[image: diag matrix]

How to implement this in MATLAB?

Comment: The pictures shows a 2d matrix of 2d matrices, wouldn't we end up with 4d?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as follows:

1. Convert the 3D array to a cell array of 3rd-dimension slices, using [`num2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html);
2. Generate a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) from the cell array; and
3. Pass that to [`blkdiag`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/blkdiag.html):

```
A(:,:,1) = [10 20 30; 40 50 60];
A(:,:,2) = A(:,:,1) + 100;
A(:,:,3) = A(:,:,1) + 200; % example 3D array
t = num2cell(A, [1 2]); % step 1
result = blkdiag(t{:}); % steps 2 and 3
```

This gives

```
result =
    10    20    30     0     0     0     0     0     0
    40    50    60     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0   110   120   130     0     0     0
     0     0     0   140   150   160     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0   210   220   230
     0     0     0     0     0     0   240   250   260
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
[a1,a2,a3] = size(a)
b{1,1} = a(:,:,1)   
b{2,2} = a(:,:,2)
b{3,3} = a(:,:,3)
```

You need to store the matrix in the form of cell matrix(denoted by "{ }" brackets)

Comment: yes. It will be a good solution if I have the `a3`=3. In my case, `a3` could be more than 100...in such case, it will be complicated.

Comment: I don't see why you can't use loop for that.

Comment: A cell is not an array. OP clearly wants an array, therefore this answer doesn't help. There's absolutely no need for a cell. Cells only complicate matters and make operations more difficult, since MATrix LABoratory is geared towards MATrices, rather than cells.